# What can cause SQL equery to run significantly longer time on different Oracle machines same SW and HW

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, configuration

I am using PL SQL procedure to aggregate data from 4 servers to one place and its has significantly lower performance on one of the servers.

I have this relatively simple query to aggregate data from the audit log:

Indexes are ok, volume of rows is bit bigger on the fourth server but not to cause this difference, same hardware, same linux, same oracle version (Oracle  11.2.0.4.0), same structure of the table and indexes. Indexes are usable, same partitioning.

INSERT INTO app_stats_agg_hourly (SHIPMENTS,event_datetime,COUNTRY,data_type,event_type,collection_time,INSTANCE)

```
    SELECT COUNT(*) as SHIPMENTS, TRUNC(event_datetime,'HH24') as event_datetime,COUNTRY,data_type,event_type,load_run_start,v_region
    FROM APP_AUDIT
    WHERE   
            event_type in ('FromApp','ToError','ToApp','Generate','FromCorr')
        and  event_datetime > last_collection
        and  event_datetime <=  last_event

    GROUP BY TRUNC(event_datetime,'HH24'),COUNTRY,data_type,event_type;
```

It works well and exactly as expected. The `last_collection` and `last_event` variables are initialized before in the procedure.
This code is running for a minute or two on 3 of 4 servers and half an hour on the fourth.

After a long investigation I found that the variables I am using are TIMESTAMPS and event_datetime column is date.  If I use date it works like a charm. My question is - what is causing this to work different?

Comment: maybe that server is busy with other stuff and the other servers are not ?

Comment: You need to look at the execution plans on the different servers.  It sounds like the types of the comparison columns might be different on different systems.

Comment: Agree.  Run the explain plans on one that is running well compared to where it is running slow.  Do you have full table scans on the slow server?

Comment: Are your optimizer statistics up-to-date on the "slow" server?

Comment: Statistics are fine, definitions are same, load is negligible on all machines. Execution plan is same when it comes to structure, just the cost on the event_column filter is extremely different. 
I changed data type of variable used to limit event datetime from timestamp to date and suddenly it works like a charm, question is, why this is not a problem on other servers. It looks like some kind of setup is preventing oracle to do automated cast from timestamp to date on one server from 3.

Comment: perhaps the default date format in that system is different

Comment: Have you gathered system statistics on all the servers?  See `dbms_stats.gather_system_stats` package.

Comment: If the datatypes do not match Oracle must perform an implicit conversion. Implicit conversions will prevent the use of indexes, and many times (like mentioned in other comments above) it can convert it incorrectly if the default date format is used. Best practice is to alway use explicit conversion (or directly date as you did) to the appropriate data type, thus fixing the issue as you stated it does. Could be something else of course, but it indicates it is related to implicit type conversion.

Comment: Implicit conversions and conversions in general are culprit of slowness. What I dont understand is why it is working on 3 servers and not on fourth. What default date format are you referring alexherm? You mean some Oracle setup or OS setup? Or something in TNS Listener? I cant find anything like this.